# Create a sub menu html

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

Hey i have quite a bit of a design to my dropdown menu and im having trouble adding a submenu to lets say to the first element on the dropdown-cotent div.

I simply want the sub menu to start where the hover of the submeneu is defined and to the right and drop down the same way as my current sub menu does it. 
Here is my html:

```
    <nav>
          <div class="main-nav">
            <ul class="left">
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Third</a>
                  <a href="#">Third Link</a>
                  <a href="#">Third Link 3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Gods</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Goddesses</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="play-now"></div>
            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="#">Heroes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Myths</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Beasts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

And here is the css to it all:

```
nav {
    padding-left: 5px
}

nav .main-nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 64px;
    background: url(../images/navHeader.png) no-repeat top;
    position: relative
}

nav .main-nav ul {
    width: 360px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none
}

nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 105px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px

}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  height: auto;
  line-height: initial;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

nav .main-nav ul a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #84827d;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

nav .main-nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7289da
}
nav .main-nav li .dropdown {

}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #3A4FC5;
    color: #656161;
    opacity: .8;
    min-width: 30px;
    top: 60px;
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #3A4FC5
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav .main-nav ul.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

nav .main-nav ul.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px
}
```

Here is snippet,

```css
nav {
    padding-left: 5px
}

nav .main-nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 64px;
    background: url(../images/navHeader.png) no-repeat top;
    position: relative
}

nav .main-nav ul {
    width: 360px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none
}

nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 105px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px

}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  height: auto;
  line-height: initial;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

nav .main-nav ul a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #84827d;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

nav .main-nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7289da
}
nav .main-nav li .dropdown {

}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #3A4FC5;
    color: #656161;
    opacity: .8;
    min-width: 30px;
    top: 60px;
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #3A4FC5
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav .main-nav ul.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

nav .main-nav ul.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul class="left">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Third</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link</a>
          <a href="#">Third Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Gods</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Goddesses</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="play-now"></div>
    <ul class="right">
      <li><a href="#">Heroes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Myths</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Beasts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Feel free to help clean my code...i know it could be done better but i dont know better.

Comment: not getting what you exactly want :)

Comment: What exactly is — not — working?

Comment: As of right now i can only manage to get one drop down menu to work. I want to add a sub menu to lets say the <a href="#">Third</a> so that also has a dropdown menu of x items.

Comment: Try using nested `<ul>`s for each dropdown level. It wil be less hard to style it and will make more sense...

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes the problem is i cant seem to format it properly with what i have...

Comment: Can you please provide me any image so i can provide you the same you want

Comment: As its not clear from the code that what you exactly want

Comment: Why would you add unnecessary jQuery here?
There is absolute no need and no requested need for jQuery. 
You should try to solve such a simple thing without JS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say this?

```css
nav {
    padding-left: 5px
}

nav .main-nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 64px;
    background: url(../images/navHeader.png) no-repeat top;
    position: relative
}

nav .main-nav > ul {
    width: 360px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none
}

nav .main-nav ul a,
nav .main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 105px;
    line-height: 80px;
    height: 80px

}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  height: auto;
  line-height: initial;
  padding: 3px 0;
}

nav .main-nav ul a {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #84827d;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out
}

nav .main-nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7289da
}
nav .main-nav li .dropdown {

}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #3A4FC5;
    color: #656161;
    opacity: .8;
    min-width: 30px;
    top: 60px;
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .main-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #3A4FC5
}

nav .main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav .main-nav ul.left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: auto !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-content ul li {
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content ul li:hover > .dropdown-content-second {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content-second {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 0 #999;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background: #3A4FC5;
    color: #656161;
    opacity: .8;
    min-width: 30px;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content-second ul li  {
    position: relative;
}

nav .main-nav ul.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="main-nav">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content-second">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">Navi 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">Navi 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">Navi 3</a>
                                        <div class="dropdown-content-second">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;">Navi 1</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;">Navi 2</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;">Navi 3</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;">Navi 4</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="javascript:;">Navi 5</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gods</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Goddesses</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="play-now"></div>
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">Heroes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Myths</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Beasts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much! How can i clean this up so it uses <ul class="dropdown-menu"> and <li class="dropdown-menu-sub"> ? all those divs kinda seem to much to me :/

Comment: I can help you with this. It would be good to have a more organized structure.

Comment: You should add ";" at the end of the lines in CSS. Furthermore i would recommend to NOT use !important tags.

Comment: Yes it is very confusing and as a beginner i would like to see more organized code so i could make it myself. I would love to see it done for my menu here...I tried it myself but it got a bit hectic and i lost a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look on my menu**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
    /* Starter CSS for Menu */
    #cssmenu {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
      width: auto;
    }
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 597;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.hover,
    #cssmenu ul li:hover {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 599;
      cursor: default;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 598;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
      float: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
      top: 0;
      left: 190px;
      width: 190px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    #cssmenu a {
      display: block;
      line-height: 1em;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* Custom CSS Styles */
    #cssmenu {
      background: #333;
      border-bottom: 4px solid #9c9797;
      font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul {
      *display: inline-block;
    }
    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu ul:after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    #cssmenu ul {
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul {
      border-top: 4px solid #9c9797;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul a {
      background: #9c9797;
      color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #837d7d;
      border-top: 0 none;
      line-height: 150%;
      padding: 16px 20px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
      border-top: 0 none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
      position: relative;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
      border-top: 1px solid #837d7d;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
      background: #b5b1b1;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
      -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
      border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
      -moz-background-clip: padding;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #9c9797;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #9c9797;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #9c9797;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a {
      -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
      border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
      -moz-background-clip: padding;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 15px;
      margin-top: -8px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul li.active > a {
      background: #9c9797;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 99.5%;
    }
    #cssmenu a {
      background: #333;
      color: #CBCBCB;
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      line-height: 48px;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
      text-align: left;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
      float: right;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
      text-align: right;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 190px;
    }
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      left: 15px;
      right: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
         <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Menus</a>
            <ul>
               <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 1.1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 1.2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 1.3</a></li>
                     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Menu 1.4</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.1</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.2</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.3</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 1.4.4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a></li>
                     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Menu 3.3</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3.1</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3.2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> About us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```